# All of my questions are about Stack Overflow; will I get reputation if I transfer them to from meta.stackexchange to meta.stackoverflow?

Tags: support, reputation

I have lots of questions on this (meta.stackexchange.com), and all of them are about Stack Overflow.

I just learned that there is also a Meta Stack Overflow. How should I transfer them, and will my reputation points also be transferred *with* the questions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your questions relate *only* to Stack Overflow, they should be on Meta Stack Overflow rather than here, though if they haven't been moved already, it's unlikely they were overtly limited to Stack Overflow.

That said, no, migrating them to Meta Stack Overflow will not earn you any reputation on Stack Overflow because participation on per-site metas does not impact your reputation on the site. It's only here on Meta Stack Exchange that reputation is awarded for votes on questions and answers.

Looking at your two undeleted questions other than this one, I don't think there's any reason to move them, though. They are applicable to the entire network, not only Stack Overflow.

Comment: However, when I visit Meta StackOverflow, I see the same reputation as my normal StackOverflow one.

Comment: Exactly. Your rep on MSO **is** your rep on Stack Overflow. The only way to earn reputation on SO is to earn it on SO. Activity on MSO doesn't get you reputation.

Comment: Oh, so that means that I can't earn *any* reputation for *anything anywhere* on MSO?

Comment: That is what I said, yes. "Participation on meta sites do not generally impact your reputation on the site". I say "generally" because this site is the one exception.

Comment: Ooooh... make sense. Thank you a lot Catija!